# How to manage time zone with DST for opencart?

Tags: opencart, cpanel, dst, opencart-3

My store location is Chichester, West Sussex, current local time is 7:30 AM, which is +1h DST,
But my store time is 6:30,
How to solve this?...
I need any of these solutions, from OpenCart dashboard/source code modification,
or
from cPanel

**Current Version is 3.0.2.0**

Comment: did you set same country and region exactly in admin>system>settings>local > country and region?

Comment: I don't see any 'county and region' option in navigation menu 
http://prntscr.com/j36sjc

Comment: Go to System>settings >edit settings > go to local tab

Comment: btw, I'm using OpenCart Version 3.0.2.0

Comment: yes, current region is set to 'West Sussex' but I need DST 
http://prntscr.com/j36tuj

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/London')
```

Worked

Answer (score 0):

Enter the required timezone for the webserver.

In system/startup.php find below code :

**find :**

`if (!ini_get('date.timezone')) {
    date_default_timezone_set('UTC');
 }`

**replace :**

`if (!ini_get('date.timezone')) {
    date_default_timezone_set('DST');
}`

Comment: I've just tried it, not working, it's returning me the same time as before.

Comment: date_default_timezone_set('United Kingdom/West Sussex');

Comment: That's not a [valid time zone identifier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones).  You should use `Europe/London` instead.